# Email signature images become extremely large after sending

Tags: html, image, email, image-resizing

I've been trying to make an HTML signature in apple mail, which seems to be working fine for me. However, when I get replies to my emails, I see that some email clients make the image extremely large. I thought I found the solution by specifying the dimensions multiple times, and it seemed to be working fine for a while, but now it has started again.

So my question is: how do I make sure the image remains the same size?

```
<!--start-->

<style type="text/css">a.link{margin:0;padding:0;border:none;text-decoration:none;}
</style>

<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"><meta name="format-detection" content="telephone=no">
<br/><br/> <!--line break-->



<!--image here-->
<table id="sig" width="320” cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border-spacing="0" style="width:320px;margin:0;padding:0;font-size: 12px;"> 
<tr> <!--indicates the row-->
<td valign="top" width="102" style="width:102px;margin:0;padding:0;">  
<a href="website" title="My Name" style="border:none;text-decoration:none;"> 
<img moz-do-not-send="true"        
src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/e/e0/Large_Scaled_Forest_Lizard.jpg" 
alt="Random Image" width="102" height="102" 
style="border:none;width:102px;height:102px;display:block"> 
</a>
</td>
<td width="10" style="width:10px;min-width:10px;max-width:10px;margin:0;padding:0;">&nbsp;
</td>


<!--here starts the text/names etc-->
<td style="margin:0;padding:0;"> 
<table id="sig2" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border-spacing="0" style="padding:0;margin:0;font-family:'Lucida Grande',sans-serif;font-size:12px;line-height:10px;color:#000000;border-collapse:collapse;-webkit-text-size-adjust:none;"> 


<tr style="margin:0;padding:0;"> 
<td style="margin:0;padding:0;font-family:'Lucida Grande',sans-serif;white-space:nowrap;"> 
<strong>
<a href="mailto:MyEmail" style="border:none;text-decoration:none;color:#000000;">
<span style="color:#000000">MyName
</span>
</a>
</strong> 

<span style="color:#00277C">|
</span>

<a href="mailto:MyEmail" style="border:none;text-decoration:none;color:#000000;">
<span style="color:#000000;font-style:italic">Function Title
</span>
</a>
</td>
</tr>



<tr>
<td height="5" style="height:5px;font-size:5px;mso-line-height-rule:exactly;line-height:5px;">&nbsp;
</td>
</tr>



<tr style="margin:0;padding:0;"> 
<td style="margin:0;padding:0;font-family:'Lucida Grande',sans-serif;white-space:nowrap;"> 
<a href="mailto:MyEmail" style="border:none;text-decoration:none;color:#000000;">
<span style="color:#000000">hello@example.com
</span>
</a> 

<span style="color:#00277C">|
</span>

<span style="color:#000000"> +1 23 45 67 89 23
</span> 
</td>
</tr>


<tr>
<td height="8" style="height:8px;font-size:8px;mso-line-height-rule:exactly;line-height:8px;">&nbsp;
</td>
</tr>




<tr style="margin:0;padding:0;"> 
<td style="margin:0;padding:0;font-family:'Lucida Grande',sans-serif;white-space:nowrap;"> 
<strong>
<span style="color:#000000">CompanyName
</span>
</strong> 
</td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td height="5" style="height:5px;font-size:5px;mso-line-height-rule:exactly;line-height:5px;">&nbsp;
</td>
</tr>


<tr style="margin:0;padding:0;"> 
<td style="margin:0;padding:0;font-family:'Lucida Grande',sans-serif;white-space:nowrap;"> 
<span style="color:#000000">Adress
</span> 

<span style="color:#00277C">|
</span>

<span style="color:#000000"> ZipCode
</span> 
</td>
</tr>


<tr>
<td height="5" style="height:5px;font-size:5px;mso-line-height-rule:exactly;line-height:5px;">&nbsp;
</td>
</tr>


<tr style="margin:0;padding:0;"> 
<td style="margin:0;padding:0;font-family:'Lucida Grande',sans-serif;white-space:nowrap;"> 
<a href="website" style="border:none;text-decoration:none;color:#000000;">
<span style="color:#000000">www.example.com
</span> 

<span style="color:#00277C">|
</span>

<span style="color:#000000"> +1 23 457 2462 35 
</span> 
</td>
</tr>







</table> 
</td>
</tr>
</table>
<br/> <!--line break-->

<!--end-->
```

I really hope someone can help me, thanks in advance!